# rand function not "defined"

Tags: c++, function, random

I am currently writing my first game (Snake) in c++ using visual Studio, I am attempting to set the blocks you eat at random areas on the screen however when I use the rand() function it says it is undefined, does anyone know why I have this error?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;
const int WIDTH = 20;
const int HEIGHT = 20;
int x, y, foodX, foodY, score;
enum eDirection { STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};
eDirection dir;
void Setup(){
    gameOver = false;
    dir = STOP;
    x = WIDTH /2;
    y = HEIGHT /2;
    //rand function below is not defined??
    //I thought the function was built in

    foodX = rand() % WIDTH;
    foodY = rand() % HEIGHT;

}

void Draw() {

}
void Input() {


}
void Logic() {


}
int main()
{
    Setup();
    while (!gameOver)
    {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an include

`#include <cstdlib>`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Answer (score 1):

`rand` is defined in the header `cstdlib` so you need to add this include:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: `rand()` is **defined** in library code somewhere that you ordinarily don't have access to. `std::rand()` is **declared** in the header `cstdlib`, and `rand()` is **declared** in the header `stdlib.h`.

Comment: A clarification to my previous comment: the compiler is complaining that the **name** `rand` has no definition. That's correct. My point is about the **function** `rand()`, which is declared in headers and defined in library code.